# How do I submit multiple Ember-CLI forms from one route?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm trying to setup a form for a new object that has multiple `belongsTo` associations. To allow users to submit a 'multi-step' form that generates new instances of the associations first, then the main object.

Specifically, a `Book` object that `belongsTo` an `Author` which, in turn, belongs to `Publisher`. I can create new instances of each object independently, but I want to make it flow through one smooth process for users.

So far, I've tried creating the `New` route for my `Book` model to include dropdown selectors for the `Author` and `Publisher` models, which I can get working for existing instances of `Author` and `Publisher` models. But, I want to allow the users to either select an existing `Author` and `Publisher` OR create new `Author` and `Publisher` instances that would be associated with the new `Book` instance.

I've looked at using a multi-step form with Components for each step as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30605534/1239238), but this is built around just the one model (in my case just the `Book` model) but that does not look like the 'correct' way to build this functionality.

Any ideas on how I could build this the Ember way?