# Step menu wizard ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

How to create step wizard for ember-cli project? I want to save data for every step .

for instance i can use `{{#link-to "company.details"}}details{{/link-to}}` to go to next step, but i want to save data before go, and then sent from another step

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ember.js - Creating a multistep wizard - How to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383834/ember-js-creating-a-multistep-wizard-how-to)

Comment: @WMeldon Thanks.It helps me, but there are not anything about saving models in server. It's very important for me. also validation each step.

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand you meant saving to the server as opposed to just retaining the data in memory.  That will definitely require some custom finagling that the above post didn't cover.